# Pusher authEndpoint doesn't trigger in react native expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, authentication, pusher, pusher-js

Here is my code on the react native code :

```
const pusher = new Pusher('app_key', {
    cluster: 'ap1',
    authEndpoint: 'http://10.0.27.124:8070/pusher/auth'
  });
 const channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
  channel.bind('uuganaa', function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

in Node js code :

```
app.post('/pusher/auth', (req, res) => {
        let socketId = req.body.socket_id;
        let channel = req.body.channel_name;
        random_string = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
        let presenceData = {
            user_id: random_string,
            user_info: {
                username: '@' + random_string,
            }
        };
        let auth = pusher.authenticate(socketId, channel, presenceData);
        res.send(auth);
    });
```

Here is my log :

```
Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-ap1.pusher.com:443/app/73286f08a5b2aeeea398?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]
Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 12784.212561977"]
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"my-channel"}}]
```

Here is called event log :

```
Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"uuganaa","channel":"my-channel","data":{"message":"Sain uu asd"}}]
```

And send request to http://10.0.27.124:8070/pusher/auth the response from the auth endpoint succesfully responding.

Why it doesn't trigger authEndpoint
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're subscribing user to a public channel. Public channels don't require authorized connection. You need to subscribe user to a private channel.

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/authorized-connections/

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/private-channels/

Comment: After that I occured this error. Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I saw your second question. I think you just have a syntax error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578131/unable-to-retrieve-auth-string-from-auth-endpoint-received-status-500/70578654#70578654