# Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 500

Tags: node.js, react-native, authentication, pusher, pusher-js

I using react native and backend is node.I trying implement pusher in my app.

```
Object {
  "error": "Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 0 from http://10.0.27.124:8070/pusher/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users",
  "status": 0,
  "type": "AuthError",
}
```

Here is my react native code :

```
  const pusher = new Pusher('73286f08a5b2aeeea398', {
    cluster: 'ap1',
    authEndpoint: 'http://10.0.27.124:8070/pusher/auth',
  });
  console.log(pusher)
  const presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe('presence-channel');
```

Here is my node js code :

```
exports.authPusher = function (req, res) {
  const socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  const channel = req.body.channel_name;
  console.log(req.body);

  const presenceData = {
    user_id: 'unique_user_id',
    user_info: { name: 'Mr Channels', twitter_id: '@pusher' },
  };
  const auth = pusher.authenticate(socketId, channel, presenceData);
  res.send(auth);
};
```

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to use quote marks around `authEndpoint` parameter. Pusher is trying to call `http` instead of `http://10.0.27.124:8070/pusher/auth`.

```
const pusher = new Pusher('73286f08a5b2aeeea398', {
  cluster: 'ap1',
  authEndpoint: 'http://10.0.27.124:8070/pusher/auth',
});
```

If you open network tab on the web-developers toolbar of your browser, you must be able to see the actual request and debug it from there.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's has quote marks.Do you have any suggestion :)

Comment: What do you see in network tab for the request that's hitting your auth endpoint? Any useful information with the error message?

Comment: Thank you for commenting :). I have fixed that issue.